# Working with JDT under eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt, helios

I'm using eclipse helios. when I import `org.eclipse...`, it triggers an error. Help > Install New Software ... says JDT is already installed! Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Plug-in Development Environment](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/) (PDE).

Comment: Thanks! I can use the jdt packages for apps other than plug ins right?

Comment: mostly used in plug-in, though you can use it in java application too. I believe for the latter you will have to add the jdt jar to the build path library.